# How can I read the rest of a file after the first 64 bytes?

Tags: file-io, java-me

I must use a file for work. First 64 byte must be a header. So I must read first 64 bytes and then read to end of file. How can I read and write a file with J2ME?

Read fully a file is that:

```
FileConnection fconn= (FileConnection) Connector.open(path+fName,Connector.READ);
InputStream is=fconn.openInputStream(); 
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
int ch;
String str = new String();
while ( (ch = dis.read()) != -1) 
{
       str+=((char)ch);
}
dis.close();
is.close();
```

And fully write a file is:

```
FileConnection fconn= (FileConnection)Connector.open(path+fName,Connector.READ_WRITE);
if(!fconn.exists()){
      items.alert=new Alert(" ","Select The Directory",null,AlertType.INFO);
      switchDisplayable(items.alert,items.getList());
      fconn.create(); 
}
os = fconn.openDataOutputStream();
fconn.truncate(0);
os.write(text.getBytes());
os.close(); 
fconn.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole file, like you're doing.
Then use this to split the data read from text:

```
// Assuming `str` contains the data read from file
String header=str.substring(0,64);
String the_rest_of_file=str.substring(64);
```

If you want to change something in the file, but not in the header, you don't really have to *skip* 64 bytes when writing. Just write the same header and then the modified data:

```
// Change `the_rest_of_file` somehow
// ...
os.write(header.getBytes());
os.write(the_rest_of_file.getBytes());
```

Comment: That' s good idea. Thank you. But how could write after 64 byte?

Comment: Edited the answer with more information. Please accept it, if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
DataInputStream.skipBytes()
```

Comment: Thank you. And If I want to  read and write only first 64 byte how can i read?